# C++ - How to open a file only by knowing part of his name

Tags: c++

In my project i need to read few files but i only know part of their name, for example:

- pacman01.screen.txt
- pacman02.screen.txt
- pacman03.screen.txt

The file name has to contain the ending (.screen) but the start may change.
how can i open those files in lexicographically order.

thanks!

Comment: [The filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) (added in the C++17 standard) will help you get a list of files. Then you can use a simple filter to filter out files not matching your requirements. Then sort the remaining files.

Comment: There is a possible [dup](/questions/68098966/find-files-by-pattern) here, but it does more than you need (it searches a whole hierarchy)